# Binary Search code keeps giving Out of Range error

Tags: python, binary-search

For binary search, I keep running into an error that the index in my code: "mid", keep being out of range. Is there any way to fix this?
Code:

```
def binary_search(num, key):
  low = 0
  high = len(num)
  while high >= low:
    mid = (low + high)//2
    if num[mid] < key:
      low = mid + 1
    elif num[mid] > key:
      low = mid + 1
    else:
      return mid
  return -1
A = [2, 4, 7, 10, 11, 32, 45, 87, 90]
print(binary_search(A, 10))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your conditions are messed up see

```py
def binary_search(num, key):
  low = 0
  high = len(num)
  while high >= low:
    mid = (low + high)//2
    if num[mid] < key:
      low = mid + 1
    elif num[mid] > key:
      high = mid - 1
    else:
      return mid
  return -1
A = [2, 4, 7, 10, 11, 32, 45, 87, 90]
print(binary_search(A, 10))
```

*inside elif

Answer (score 0):

Issues in your code:

- You are changing only `low` in your code everytime.
  `high` remains unchanged.
- When `num[mid] > key` then the key lies to the left of `mid`. So `high = mid - 1`.

This should be the correct implementation.

```
def binary_search(num, key):
  low = 0
  high = len(num)-1
  while high >= low:
    mid = (low + high)//2
    if num[mid] < key:
      low = mid + 1
    elif num[mid] > key:
      high = mid - 1
    else:
      return mid
  return -1
A = [2, 4, 7, 10, 11, 32, 45, 87, 90]
print(binary_search(A, 11))
```